# footer static positioned at the bottom of page

Tags: css, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5 and need a footer to be at the bottom of every page.
Currently I have the footer in app.blade.php along with a nav bar and the content coming from other .blade files using yields **@yield('content')**

the app.blade file has

```
html, body {   
 height: 100%;
}
```

and the footer is

```
footer {
  position: static;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

When inspecting the page the html and body are 100% height but the footer is just hanging out with the content and not shifting to the bottom of the page.

Are there any larvel related styles that could be interfering with the positioning?

Comment: You should be using `position: absolute`, `bottom`, `left`, `top` and `right` properties will have no effect on `position: static` elements, only on *positioned* elements; positioned elements are relatively (`relative`) and absolutely (`fixed` and `absolute`) positioned elements (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). I'm not mentioning `position: sticky` since `sticky` is an *experimental API* and shouldn't be used in production as it is not yet fully supported and integrated into all browsers (see https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky for browser compatibility).

Comment: Some practical examples using `relative` positioning (https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/KyzJZg) and `fixed` positioning (https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/ooxmMQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think laravel styling has anything to do with the problem. Setting the `position`property to `static` isn't going to give you the results you're looking for, as `static` is the default `position` value for almost every html element. You could set it to `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky` and depending on your choice you might need to set the `bottom` property on your footer to `0px`.

This [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/bottom/) should give you a better idea of how you want to implement the `position` and `bottom` properties on your footer.

Here's an implementation using the `fixed` value on the footer and a `relative` value on the body element.

You can also view this [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/sltPTQpait) and experiment with changing the footer's `position` value.

```
html, body {   
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: i ended up using **static** as  **sticky** and **fixed** was behaving the same, that's why i was thinking it was being overwritten but inspecting the element shows nothing that's re positioning it after my css.

Comment: Is the problem still persisting? If it is try the CSS I added to my answer, minus background-color properties.

Comment: yeah, the problem is still persisting. I decided to go with some JS to fix it for now. My layout works on a separate frontend only document I've been using to sandbox ideas (using fixed positioning and then some JS to display none unless at the bottom of the page). not the best solution but it works for now